# Colliders along the edge of the sprite

Tags: unity

I am trying to make a collider along the edges of my sprite, something like what an outline shader does. I tried adding a polygon collider 2D as you can see below but it doesn’t take the shape of the sprite. Any help is appreciated

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR45l.jpg

Comment: Did you try clicking the edit collider button to fit the collider polygon more closely to your sprite's shape?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to do this at runtime. The collider has to adjust to the shape of the sprite at runtime

Comment: If you have extra requirements to add to your question, please edit your question to include them.

Comment: Maybe genetate collider shapes in advance and enable/disable them in the animation together with the sprite frames. BTW very complex collision shapes often "feel" worse han simpler collisions.